# Pass property into a class when creating an instance of an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, interface

I have this interface:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    string Subject { get; }
    string Body { get; }
    string ToAddress { get; }
}
```

And then a class that implements it:

```
public class RestoreEntityMessage : IMessage
{
    public string Subject
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntitySubject"]; }
    }
    public string Body
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntityBody"]; }
    }
    public string ToAddress
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntitryToAddress"]; }
    }
}
```

Then when it's used:

```
IMessage message = new RetireEntityMessage();
```

But, I need to pass a string into `Body` that will be unique per instance.  So, back in `RestoreEntityMessage`  I need to do something like this:

```
public string Body
{
    get { return myVar + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntityBody"]; 
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get `myVar` all the way there. Can I do something like this?

```
IMessage message = new RetireEntityMessage(myVar);
```

And if so, how do I modify the class / interface to accept the parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have constructors in interfaces, but that also means your interface is indifferent to any constructor in your code.

If you change your class to this:

```
public class RestoreEntityMessage : IMessage
{
    private string _someString;
    public RetireEntityMessage(string someString)
    {
        _someString = someString;
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get { return _someString + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntityBody"]; 
    }

    public string Subject
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntitySubject"]; }
    }

    public string ToAddress
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntitryToAddress"]; }
    }
}
```

Everything should be ok.

Think about what an interface does.  It is a contract for what an object looks like.  It does not care about its creation, only that it has the *shape* that you define.  Adding this constructor does not break anything because you are still implementing the members of the interface.

Comment: Good explanation.  He could also set the _somString variable directly, and use an empty constructor.  While that's not ideal and doesn't really make any sense, given his objective, I just wanted to point out that it IS possible.  Of course, with that route, calling the Body property prior to setting _someString could yield unexpected results or errors, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just add a constructor to the class...

```
public class RestoreEntityMessage : IMessage
{
    private string _myvar;

    public RestoreEntityMessage(string myvar)
    {
        _myvar = myvar;
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get { return _myvar + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RestoreEntityBody"]; }
    }       
}
```